# Create new table in Rails joining fields from another database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, csv

In my church website, many members are married couples. I have a csv file from the membership database, which uses a seven-digit identifier that looks like this:

```
  00903 1
```

and the spouse of that person will be

```
  00903 2
```

What I would like to do is to create a table of couples and their anniversaries. How would I get a row to contain

```
  her_first_name:string his_first_name:string family_name:string.
```

In other words, how would I combine information from two records into one record, when the only way to identify how the two are linked is the last "digit" in a string? Is Regex involved, and if so, what does the query look like? Thanks

Comment: RailsCasts, as well as many other free online resources, can help you understand importing data from csv into a Rails app. Here is a RailsCast episode as a starting point: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

Comment: I pretty much know how to import a csv file. My question has to do with how to combine two individuals to create one couple.

Comment: Haven't heard any feedback - is my answer what you are looking for? Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Michael: Thanks for checking. I had to tend to other issues, and I intend to get back to this today. Your answer looks to exactly fit my question and I appreciate your effort and look forward to implementing it and signing off on this part of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to do something like this (I'm assuming that it's always the same format, where for a couple, the first 5 digits are actually the same. I'm also assuming that you need to check if each record has a spouse, not that you already know they are married. Finally, I'm assuming you have a model named `Couple` with an associated `couples` table, a model named Person for individual members which has `ind_id` field as the identifier, and I'm making up the row positions for each field.):

```
individuals = [] # an array that can hold each record until a spouse is found in the csv

csv.each do |row|
  id_regexp = Regexp.new(row[0][0..4] + '.') # creates a regexp out of the first 5 characters in the id, then adds '.' to match any following characters
  spouse = individuals.select { |individual| individual.ind_id =~ id_regexp }.first #searches individuals for that regexp, returns the first instance if it exists, or nil otherwise
  if spouse
    couple = Couple.new(wife_name: spouse.first_name, husband_name: row[1], last_name: row[2], anniversary: row[3], etc.) # if a spouse was found create a Couple record
    couple.save!
    individuals.delete(spouse) # remove this record from the array so there is one less record to iterate over on the next loop
  else
    individuals << Person.new(first_name: row[1], last_name: row[2], etc.) # build a Person and store it in the array. You could persist the Person to the db if you are saving individuals with this import as well
  end
end
```

Now, you could add a check in there, given a spouse is found, that checks to see which is the husband and which is the wife depending on the `1` or the `2` in the `ind_id[6]` slot:

```
 if spouse.ind_id[6] == '1'
   couple.wife_name = spouse.first_name
   couple.husband_name = row[1]
 else
   couple.husband_name = spouse.first_name
   couple.wife_name = row[1]
 end
```

This would obviously go in between the `couple = Couple.new(...` and the `couple.save!`.

Anyway, I had to assume a lot because of the amount of detail provided in your OP, but hopefully this gives you a template to go off of. If you don't have `Person` class, you could just create a hash and push that into `individuals` each time and compare `individual[:ind_id]` in the `select`.

**Note**

I used Regexp because you specified this. Could just as easily do

```
base_id = row[0][0..4]
spouse = individuals.select { |individual| individual.ind_id[0..4] == base_id }.first
```